# User Management module in Microservices Application

Tags: microservices

We have created a User Registration microservice that currently only registers the Users, Now we are planning to have the User profile management module. So our question is should we create a new microservice for User Profile management or use the same User Registration microservice.

what is the best practice?

Thanks